# Bioacoustics jobs – where are they how to find them?

Tags: career, jobs

Other than academia and government (e.g. in the U.S., National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration (NOAA) and Navy), what other bioacoustics career options are there?

How are people finding these jobs? E.g., other than a [few jobs listed on the ASA website](https://acousticalsociety.org/jobs/), there aren’t any bioacoustics job boards that I am aware of.

What about international (outside of the U.S., in this case) career options and job resources?

Comment: By the way: an international audience doesn't know what NOAA is

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I added the full name.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> ***This answer is a Wiki!** Edit it to add more suggestions.*

- The [WILDLABS acoustic monitoring group](https://wildlabs.net/groups/acoustic-monitoring) is a good place to look! Lots of job & funding opportunities posted.
- The [Conservation Tech Directory](https://conservationtech.directory/) is also a good place to look for both job boards themselves as well as organizations, companies, academic labs, etc. that do applied bioacoustics or passive acoustic monitoring - you can search by keywords & filter by different parameters.
- The bioacoustics list serv (bioacoustics-l@cornell.edu) is a good resource for job postings. Instructions to join can be found at the [list servs FAQ here](http://bioacoustics.cse.unsw.edu.au/archives/html/bioacoustics-l/2002-05/msg00010.html) but those instructions seem out of date (from feedback here) so you can contact the Holger Klinck at the K. Lisa Yang Center for Conservation Bioacoustics via email to be added.
- The International Bioacoustics Conference (IBAC) has a listserv as well, similar to Cornell's listserv that Selene referenced above! You can subscribe to it through the [website](https://www.ibac.info/) (look on the right-hand side for the link to join the listserv).
- If you subscribe to MARMAM Digest, they send out job listings (international) as well as other marine mammal science related information: https://lists.uvic.ca/mailman/listinfo/marmam.
- There are companies that hire bioacousticians and do research. JASCO Applied Sciences provides consulting and research services for assessing and mitigating underwater noise: https://www.jasco.com/careers. SMRU Consulting may also hire people with bioacoustics backgrounds: https://www.smruconsulting.com/.
- Aquariums and ocean institutes also often have acousticians doing research.
- When at conferences and workshops (such as the upcoming Biennial Conference on the Biology of Marine Mammals) it can be helpful to take note of the various organizations people work for, e.g., Ocean Science Analytics (https://www.oceanscienceanalytics.com/our-services).
- Mostly for UK but check in on the UK Acoustic Network
  (https://acoustics.ac.uk/ ) - Bioacoustics Special Interest Group (SIGBio) - for job postings updating regularly:
  https://acoustics.ac.uk/sigs/bioacoustics-sigbio/.
  PS: free for anyone to join.

Comment: I just joined the WILDLABS acoustic monitoring group. Did we have the chance to share the beta with the community? Or have been already done?

Comment: I think someone posted about it back when it first launched but I haven't seen anything of late (since the Beta stage started). But anyone can post a thread in the new WILDLABS site so definitely go for it!

Comment: @angie_zorka I've compiled the answers to your question into this one answer, and made it a wiki for us all to edit. It would be handy if you could select it as the "Accepted" answer

Comment: @DanStowell - I think I did it? I’m at sea and trying to do this on my phone… ‍♀️

Answer (score 26):

The bioacoustics list serv (bioacoustics-l@cornell.edu) is a good resource for job postings.

Instructions to join from the list servs FAQ:

> 2. How do I subscribe/change address/unsubscribe?
>
>    To subscribe to Bioacoustics-L, send mail to
>    [EMAIL PROTECTED] with the message contents of
>
>    ```
>      SUBSCRIBE Bioacoustics-L <your real name>
>    ```
>
>    and you'll be automatically included in the list of
>    subscribers.  Be sure to use your real name, rather than your
>    email address, like this:
>
>    ```
>      SUBSCRIBE Bioacoustics-L Albert Einstein
>    ```
>
>    The mailing-list software automatically gets your email address
>    from the header of your message.  The subject line is ignored.
>    Note that the software tries to interpret EVERY line of the
>    message body as a command, so any "signature" text appended by
>    your mailer will confuse it.
>
>    When you first subscribe, you will receive a list password,
>    which is a string of digits.  Save this password, and use it to
>    change your email address, like this:
>
>    ```
>      SET Bioacoustics-L ADDRESS <password> <new email address>
>    ```
>
>    To stop getting messages from the list, send a message like this:
>
>    ```
>      UNSUBSCRIBE Bioacoustics-L
>    ```

Additional FAQ for this list serv (from 2002!) can be found [here](http://bioacoustics.cse.unsw.edu.au/archives/html/bioacoustics-l/2002-05/msg00010.html)

Comment: Does anyone know what email address should be there in place of [EMAIL PROTECTED]? I tried bioacoustics-l@cornell.edu and got an error.

Comment: @EricSnyder I thought that was the correct email...let me see if I can find out if that is incorrect

Comment: @EricSnyder Apparently it used to work to automate that but the list serv manager needs to look into why it isn't currently working. For now, you can email holger.klinck@cornell.edu and ask to be added.

Answer (score 14):

If you subscribe to MARMAM Digest, they send out job listings (international) as well as other marine mammal science related information: https://lists.uvic.ca/mailman/listinfo/marmam.

There are companies that hire bioacousticians and do research. JASCO Applied Sciences provides consulting and research services for assessing and mitigating underwater noise: https://www.jasco.com/careers. SMRU Consulting may also hire people with bioacoustics backgrounds: https://www.smruconsulting.com/.

Aquariums and ocean institutes also often have acousticians doing research.

When at conferences and workshops (such as the upcoming Biennial Conference on the Biology of Marine Mammals) it can be helpful to take note of the various organizations people work for. I just noticed someone was from Ocean Science Analytics (https://www.oceanscienceanalytics.com/our-services), which I had never heard of before.

Answer (score 9):

Mostly for UK but check in on the UK Acoustic Network
(https://acoustics.ac.uk/ ) - Bioacoustics Special Interest Group (SIGBio) - for job postings updating regularly:
https://acoustics.ac.uk/sigs/bioacoustics-sigbio/.
PS: free for anyone to join.

Answer (score 7):

Another thought for those interested in marine mammals is monitoring the (MARMAM -- Marine Mammals Research and Conservation Discussion) email list which has been going since 1993. There are regular international job postings many of which are bioacoustic related. This is also an excellent source of recent advances and papers. You can subscribe for free here: https://lists.uvic.ca/mailman/listinfo/marmam.

Comment: Apologies I can see that this was already suggested above. Sorry AWestell